# Why can't I pass a pointer as an argument?

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to retrieve a pointer via a function in c.  If the pointer is a return value from the function then it works.  But if I pass the address of the pointer to the function, I can't update the dereferenced pointer value (which should be the address stored in the pointer) from within the function.

Please see the code and the output.  Why don't I get the same results with both `GetPointer1()` and `GetPointer2()`?  What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t SrcArray[2][3] = {{11,12,13},{21,22,23}};
uint8_t *p1;
uint8_t *p2;

void GetPointer1(uint8_t *p);
uint8_t* GetPointer2(void);

int main()
{
    printf ("&SrcArray[0][0]: %d\n", &SrcArray[0][0]);

    GetPointer1(p1);
    p2 = GetPointer2();

    printf ("p1: %d\n",p1);
    printf ("p2: %d\n",p2);

    return 0;
}

void GetPointer1(uint8_t *p)
{
    p = &SrcArray[0][0];
}

uint8_t* GetPointer2(void)
{
    return &SrcArray[0][0];
}
```

Output:

```
&SrcArray[0][0]: 6295604
p1: 0
p2: 6295604
```

Comment: pass it like this: `GetPointer1(&p1);`

Comment: It should be noted that a function like `void GetPointer1(uint8_t *p)
{
    p = &SrcArray[0][0];
}` is bad programming practice. First of all, the function is completely superfluous. Second, using functions to modify a global variable which is not one of the parameters is almost always a bad idea, since it is very poor design. _Unless_ these functions are part of an API and `SrcArray` is declared as a local `static` inside some library, then it could possibly even be good programming practice. And in multi-process systems, keep in mind that none of this code is re-entrant.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, you called it right. I have a static multidimensional array. I am making an API and I want to return a pointer to a specific row of the array. And it's for a bare-metal microcontroller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the pointer you have in the function signature of GetPointer1(uint8_t *p) is passed by value. If you want to modify the pointer itself, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void GetPointer1(uint8_t **p) {
    *p = &SrcArray[0][0];
}
```

Otherwise, you may modify the piece memory to which the pointer points, but not the pointer itself.

Comment: Thanks; that is what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

Its is local to function `GetPointer1` because it is a local variable which is passed as an value not as an address.
Here is the output details of your code for better understanding

```
inside main: &SrcArray[0][0]: 6295616
value of pointer p1: 0
address of pointer p1: 6295640
inside GetPointer1: 0
value of pointer p: 0 //which ur taking to a pointer p and modifying p whihc is local to that function.
address of pointer p: 64030024
inside GetPointer1 after assignment:value of pointer p: 6295616
address of pointer p: 64030024
```

If you want to pass address you need to use `&` before the  variable say `&p1`. 
Also as mentioned in one of the answer by IGarFieldI you can use pointer to a pointer.

```
void GetPointer1(uint8_t **p) {
    *p = &SrcArray[0][0];
}
```

One more point since `P1` is global variable, its accessible to all the functions you can directly use `P1=SrcArray;` which is allowed and does the same task.
`ScrArray` is equivalent `&ScrArray[][]` both gives the address of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable p1 that is pointing to something. Then you pass it to a function GetPointer1. What happens there is that the value of the variable p1 (this is the address of the value it is pointing to!!!) is **copied (!)** to the function stack. This means that you can modify the pointed value (`*p1`), but not the original pointer (`p1`) itself, as you only have a copy of it. If you want to be able to modify the original pointer, then you have to retrieve the address of the pointer and pass this one to the function, i. e. you need a pointer to the pointer. You get this via the address-of operator &. So you need this:

```
getPointer1(uint8_t** p) { *p = /*...*/; }
```

and call it via

```
getPointer1(&p1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int SrcArray[2][3] = {{11,12,13},{21,22,23}};
int *p1;
int *p2;

void GetPointer1(int **p);
int* GetPointer2(void);

int main()
{
    printf ("&SrcArray[0][0]: %d\n", SrcArray[0][0]);

    GetPointer1(&p1); /*<-- passing the reference of pointer p1 */
    p2 = GetPointer2();

    printf ("p1: %d\n",*p1);
    printf ("p2: %d\n",*p2);

    return 0;
}

void GetPointer1(int **p) /*<-- using double pointer */
{
    *p = &SrcArray[0][0];
}

int* GetPointer2(void)
{
    return &SrcArray[0][0];
}

o/p
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc -g stack3.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
&SrcArray[0][0]: 11
p1: 11
p2: 11
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$
```

Comment: To make this a useful answer you should explain what you've changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

" But if I pass the address of the pointer to the function." But you're not passing the address of the pointer, you're passing a copy of the pointer; changing the copy (as you noticed), doesn't change the original. If you actually pass in the &p (address of p) like you intended, you will be able to modify it - I'm unsure of syntax.  edit: void GetPointer1(uint8_t **p) maybe?